# Insert "Golf" fails in SQL Server with error unclosed quotation mark

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, quotation-marks

Very simple table and insert statement, fails if the string is 'Golf', but works for any other string.
Table create:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[market]
(
    [marketID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [name] [varchar](50) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_market] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([marketID] ASC)
)
```

Insert:

```
INSERT [dbo].[market] ([marketID], [name]) VALUES (4, N'Golf')

Error: Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ''. (State:37000, Native Code: 69)
Error: Incorrect syntax near ''. (State:37000, Native Code: 66)
Error: Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ')'.
```

Now, if I change the insert to:

```
INSERT [dbo].[market] ([marketID], [name]) VALUES (4, N'Test')
```

It works just fine.  Has anyone ever seen that before?

Comment: Seems to work just fine on SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/263f9/1/0

Comment: What application are you running this in? Does it alter the query in any way? Perhaps dodgy home made parsing of `GO`?

Comment: I think you select half of the query and then run then it will give error, either it's not possible to give error because both statement are identical.

Comment: The only thing that I can see ist that you are inserting a Unicode string into a non-unicode column - `name` is of type `varchar` and you insert `N'Golf'`

Answer (score 3):

I think the application you are using must be broken and splits into batches if a GO is found anywhere in the string.

e.g. it uses a naive approach such as the below.

```
Regex.Split(sqlString, "GO", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Then executes the results as separate batches.

Running

```
INSERT [dbo].[market] ([marketID], [name]) VALUES (4, N'
```

Returns the first two errors you report.

> Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Unclosed quotation mark after the
>   character string ''.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect
>   syntax near ''.

Executing

```
lf')
```

Returns the third one.

> Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Unclosed quotation mark after the
>   character string ') '.

A temporary workaround might be to try

```
INSERT [dbo].[market] ([marketID], [name]) VALUES (4, N'G' + 'olf')
```

But of course the application really needs to be fixed.